# Synchronize Outlook calendar to Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've been trying without success to synchronize **an existing Outlook Calendar** to a Sharepoint one. Or even to display an existing Outlook Calendar in Sharepoint.

I know and I've been able to do the opposite, I mean synchronize a Sharepoint Calendar to an Outlook one but **that's not what I want** because my existing Outlook calendar is shared with a list and I don't want to change that.

I have found many topics on this but no answers to my problem.

I'm now wondering if this is even possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Which versions of SharePoint and Outlook/Exchange are you using?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Calendars are a one way setup with 2 way functionality.  What that means is you are allowed to see and edit a SharePoint calendar in Outlook.  But you can't push or pull a calendar from Outlook into SharePoint.

What you can do is create the calendar in SharePoint, connect it to your Outlook, and Copy/Paste or Drag/Drop from your original Outlook calendar into the connected SP calendar while in Outlook. This could reduce typing, but is still a manual process.

I haven't used it, but there is/was a webpart for MyCalendar.  Where SharePoint would show you your calendar from Outlook on the SharePoint page.  But it wouldn't show a shared calendar or someone else's calendar.  It would go fetch it when you opened the page.